# A plugin that downloads other plugins

Tags: plugins

Is it possible to create a plugin that allows me to download certain plugins from the WordPress repository?
I wish to install my custom plugin and from a list of plugin in it, i want to download them.

Because i need specific plugins for every site.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lots of Premium theme use http://tgmpluginactivation.com/.
It should do the job.